# Accessing object property with variable

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have an object full of arrays, I am able to change an element in an array with this code

```
$i = 0;
$object->property[$i] = "some value";
```

however the following code does not change the value and returns no errors.

```
 $i = 0;
 $propertyname = "property";
 $object->$propertyname[$i] = "some value";
```

Comment: Try this `$object->{"$propertyname[$i]"} = 'some value';`.

Comment: didn't make any difference :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
 $i = 0;
 $propertyname = "property";
 $object->{$propertyname}[$i] = "some value";
```

Comment: @Alex To tell php the property name is `$propertyname` but not `$propertyname[$i]`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to set a property you should use functions. 
This prevents to set properties to invalid values.
What you want to achieve can be done by a workaround:

```
public function setPoperty($propName,$Value)
{
   switch($propName)
   {
      case ('firstName'):
         $this->firstName=$Value;
         break;
      case ('UserMode'):
         if ($Value>0)       //prevent from setting to an undesired value
         { $this->UserMode=$Value}
         break;
   }
}
```

This is just written from scratch. But you should get the idea.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like your trying to edit data encapsulated in object by procedural style

E: try

$object->$propertyname[$otherprop['name']$i];